# Creating diff from a tar

Tags: linux, backup, tar, incremental-backup

There is a tar file which was created few days before, this tar file was created on the /files directory.

And now /files directory has new files uploaded in it.

My question is how to create another files with only the new files uploaded.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you want to do a [incremental backup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_backup) (Also look at differential to see if that is what you want).  Here is good tutorial on how to do [incremental backups with tar](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec305.html).

If you want just a diff, than use the `-d` switch (at least with GNU tar):

```
-d, --diff, --compare
              find differences between archive and file system
```

So for example `tar -df foo.tar *`

Comment: Unfortunately `--diff` only compares against files already in the archive, so new files in the directory will not be listed.